# SWIG: How to pass list of complex from c++ to python

Tags: python, c++, list, swig, complex-numbers

I have a function in c++ who returns a list of complex:

```
#include <complex>
std::list< std::complex<double> > func(...);
```

what should i do in the '*.i' file ?

Thank you every body.

=================

Following are details:

the function i would like to use in python in x.h:

```
std::list<std::complex<double> > roots1(const double& d, const double& e);
```

I have tried some ways:

(1) x.i:

```
%include <std_list.i>
%include <std_complex.i>
```

than I try in IPython:

```
tmp = x.roots1(1.0, 2.0)
len(tmp)
```

and I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-9ebf7dab7cd9> in <module>()
----> 1 len(tmp)

TypeError: object of type 'SwigPyObject' has no len()
```

and:

```
dir(tmp)
```

returns:

```
[ 
...
'acquire',
'append',
'disown',
'next',
'own']
```

(2) x.i:

```
%include <std_list.i>
%include <std_complex.i>
namespace std {
    %template(ComplexDouble)        complex<double>;
}
```

than, i got compile error:

```
error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [py] Error 1
```

(3) in x.i:

```
%include <std_list.i>
%include <std_complex.i>
namespace std {
    %template(ComplexDouble)        list<complex<double> >;
}
```

or:

```
%include <std_list.i>
%include <std_complex.i>
namespace std {
    %template(ComplexDouble)        list<complex>;
}
```

and I got:

```
x_wrap.cpp:5673:32: error: ‘complex’ was not declared in this scope
 template <>  struct traits<complex > {
                            ^
```

================================================

(Mr./Ms./Mrs) m7thon help me find the problem.
In my python context:

```
Ubuntu: 45~14.04.1
Python:  3.4.3
SWIG:    SWIG Version 2.0.11
         Compiled with g++ [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
         Configured options: +pcre
```

if define the x.i as:

```
%include <std_list.i>
%include <std_complex.i>
namespace std {
    %template(ComplexList)        list<complex<double> >;
}
```

there will be compiling error. But it works if x.i:

```
%include <std_list.i>
%include <std_complex.i>
%template(ComplexList) std::list< std::complex<double> >;
```

Thank you m7thon.

Comment: Hi, I have rewrote the question. Could you help me? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
%include <std_list.i>
%include <std_complex.i>
%template(ComplexList) std::list<std::complex<double> >;
... (your includes / function declarations)
```

I think your version (3) should actually also work. Strange that it doesn't. Maybe a SWIG bug.

Comment: Yes, your code works in my python context (`45~14.04.1-Ubuntu + Python 3.4.3`). And SWIG information is (`SWIG Version 2.0.11

Compiled with g++ [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]

Configured options: +pcre`)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. As a note: You do not need to / should not edit your question to include the answer and say thanks. That is what the answer(s) are there for. A comment to the answer is a perfect place for a quick thank you.

Comment: got it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To be more concise you can use the whole namespace:

```
%include <std_list.i>
%include <std_complex.i>

using namespace std;

%template(ComplexList) list<complex<double> >;
```

But the initially suggested versions of including SWIG `%template` into the `std` namespace is not a good idea.